# Are linear regression errors independent? Mean independent? Uncorrelated?

Tags: regression, linear-model, error, assumptions, proof

All I know is that we assume zero conditional mean (and hence zero mean) and conditional homoscedasticity (and hence homoscedasticity).

When trying to prove that $E[(\hat{\beta_1} - \beta_1)\bar{u}] = 0$, where $\beta_1$ is the slope in the linear regression model, $\hat{\beta_1}$ is its estimate and $\bar{u}$ is the average of the errors in the linear regression model (not the residuals!), I encountered:

$$E[(\hat{\beta_1} - \beta_1)\bar{u}|x]$$

$$\vdots$$

$$ = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(x_i - \bar{x})}{SST_x} \color{red}{[\sum_{j=1}^{n} E[(u_i)u_j|x]]}$$

$$ = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(x_i - \bar{x})}{SST_x} \color{red}{\sigma^2}$$

$$\vdots$$

$$ = 0 $$

$$\to E[(\hat{\beta_1} - \beta_1)\bar{u}] = 0$$

QED

---

What is the justification for that part? I tried:

For $i \ne j$, we have $E[(u_i)u_j|x] = Cov[u_i,u_j|x] + E[(u_i)|x]E[u_j|x] \stackrel{(*)}{=} 0 + (0)(0) = 0$

For $i = j$, we have $E[(u_i)u_j|x] = E[(u_i^2)|x] = Var[u_i|x] = \sigma^2$

Is $(*)$ right?

If so, what is the justification?

If not, how does one show that $E[u_i u_j | x] = 0$?

---

From Wooldridge:

---

[image]

---

This is from $(ii)$ of this exercise:

---

[image]

Comment: The errors are assumed to be uncorrelated.

Comment: @dsaxton How do you know? It doesn't seem to be part of the assumptions of SLR

Comment: Scroll down to assumptions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression.  If you didn't assume the errors were uncorrelated then how else would you conclude this?  You can easily imagine a model satisfying all the other conditions where the errors are correlated.

Comment: @dsaxton I know it's uncorrelated, mean independent or independent. I wanted to know which specifically it was. 'Independence of errors. This assumes that the errors of the response variables are uncorrelated with each other.' Should I find it strange that the book doesn't include that?

Comment: @dsaxton Wait so is it independent? Or just uncorrelated?

Comment: Sometimes independence is stated as an assumption, but lack of correlation should always be.  You can find it here as well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Markov_theorem.  If you already knew this I'm not sure why you'd ask for help in showing $\text{E}(u_i u_j) = 0$.

Comment: @dsaxton Oh sorry I mean I knew it was uncorrelated or something else based on what I read before, but this particular book doesn't seem to have anything. Might there be a way of deducing uncorrelatedness from another assumption here?

Comment: As I commented before, uncorrelatedness doesn't follow from the other assumptions, otherwise it wouldn't need to be stated as an additional assumption as it is.

Comment: @dsaxton So Wooldridge's assumptions are incomplete?

Comment: @BCLC independence follows from the random sampling assumption, see answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key thing here is that Wooldridge makes the assumption of random sampling.

Notice that since we have a random sample this means $(x_i, y_i) \perp (x_j, y_j)$ for $i \neq j$ which means that the single components of the pair are also independent, in particular $x_i \perp x_j$ (to see that just notice the joint is $p(x_i, y_i, x_j, y_j) = p(x_i, y_i)p (x_j, y_j)$ and marginalize over $y$).

This further implies $y_i \perp y_j |x_i, x_j$, since:

$$
p(y_i, y_j|x_i, x_j) = \frac{p(x_i, y_i, x_j, y_j)}{p(x_i, x_j)} = \frac{p(x_i, y_i)p (x_j, y_j)}{p(x_i)p(x_j)} = p(y_i|x_i)p(y_j|x_j)
$$

But $y_i|x_i$ is nothing more than the disturbance $u_i$ plus a constant. Hence $u_i \perp u_j |x$ when assuming a random sample and $E[u_i u_j | x] =E[u_i|x] E[u_j | x] =  0$

Comment: Oh I think I get it we just write $u_m=y_m-b0-b1x_m$ and then apply all that you said to show the penultimate equation you have? Also are introductory econometric students expected to get this?

Comment: That’s one way to think about it. Regarding introductory students, not really, my experience is that people usually memorize the error terms are independent/uncorrelated with  random sampling.

Comment: Actually, you have to be a little more precise about what "random sample" actually means.  In finite populations, elements of simple random samples are *not* independent. So you really do have to assume independence, unless "random sampling" has previously been defined as "independent sampling."

Comment: @CarlosCinelli, could you clarify the notation in the last paragraph? Is the x without a subscript a vector, i.e., x = (x_i, x_j)? And if other covariates were included, say, z_i, would it be appropriate to write E(u_i, u_j | x_i, x_j, z_i, z_j) = 0?