# Assumptions about data distribution for OLS

Tags: regression, maximum-likelihood, least-squares, iid

From all the content I have read, ordinary least squares (OLS) assumes that the errors are normally distributed i.i.d. I still cannot find any content that gives a bit more insight on what can be inferred about the distribution of (Xi, yi).

From what I read [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/554828/408276) it seems like having i.i.d assumptions on (Xi, yi) is a **much stronger assumption** and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/315214/408276) the author says that independent samples of (Xi, yi) is sufficient.

I would like to check whether the only assumption on (Xi, yi) is that they are independently sampled? Does this mean one could sample (Xi, yi) from a i.n.i.d (independent but not identically distributed) distribution and as long as the errors are i.i.d OLS would work?

Comment: Your first question regarding what the distributional assumption on the error implies about the marginal distribution of $y_i$ is [answered here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/375892). Nontrivial assumptions about the *joint* distribution of $(X_i, y_i)$ are not usually made in linear regression; instead $X_i$ is [usually treated as fixed](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/246047) (i.e., non-random, without a probability distribution of its own).